# Matching with Regex in Javascript (Optional substring)

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

**String:**

```
<p>[element title="Some title"]Some random text[/element]
[element]Some random text[/element]</p>
```

**Need to extract:**

1) Element title (optional) - 'Some title'

2) Element content - 'Some Random Text'

http://regex101.com/r/eB0jE6/1

**How to make title in the element optional?**

Comment: You... Put the stuff to make optional in a group and quantify it as optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the title part inside a  non-capturing group and then make it as optional.

```
\[element(?:\stitle="([^"]+)")?]([^\[\]]*)\[\/element\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eB0jE6/2)